# Git rebase no argument version vs one argument version

Tags: git, rebase, pull

I went through reading a bunch of stuff on SO and the Git docs, and noticed something, after messing around, that I don't completely understand:

Let's say I have the following state and configuration post-fetch, stage 2 of a git pull, and a forced update has occurred on origin/master:

```
$ git log -2 --oneline
a589c89 foo2
e0e5946 foo

$ git log -2 --oneline origin/master
e0e5946 foo

$ git config branch.master.remote
origin

$ git config branch.master.rebase
true

$ git config branch.master.merge
refs/heads/master
```

The doc says (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)

```
If <branch> is specified, git rebase will perform an automatic git
checkout <branch> before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on
the current branch.

If <upstream> is not specified, the upstream configured in
branch.<name>.remote and branch.<name>.merge options will be used
```

When I specify the single argument version of git rebase this happens:

```
$ git rebase origin/master
Pruned remote csv test branches
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.

$ git log -2 --oneline
a589c89 foo2
e0e5946 foo
```

Cool, foo2 still exists on my local branch as expected. Now doing this, which should be the same thing (implicitly) because according to the docs, branch.master.remote and branch.master.merge resolve as origin/master as shown above, unless I'm interpreting things wrong:

```
$ git rebase
Pruned remote csv test branches
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.

$ git log -2 --oneline
e0e5946 foo
```

Except foo2 is lost and we have to do `git reset --hard HEAD@{2}` to recover. Wasn’t really expecting that one. Any idea why I'm getting different behavior here? And how would I go about preventing foo2 from being lost in the process **without** switching branch.master.rebase to false? I intend for the pull to do a rebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference depends on your specific Git version.

Currently (Git versions above 2.something, I am not sure off-hand what the something is), the biggest difference is that the three-argument version *disables* `--fork-point` by default, while the two-argument version *enables* it by default.

Introducing `git pull` into the mix makes things even trickier, because `git pull` is where `--fork-point` originated, and older versions of Git behave much more differently than newer ones.  In particular, before `--fork-point` was its own separate option, *only* `git pull` did fork-point style rebasing.  I doubt this is an issue in your particular Git version, as then you would not see a difference with `git rebase origin/master` vs `git rebase` (with `branch.master.*` configurations supplying the `<upstream>`).  At least, I think you would not.

(For completeness, you might want to show the output of `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch`, although I expect it to be the standard single line of `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.)

Further reading on `--fork-point`: [the `git rebase` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) and [the `git merge-base` documentation section on `--fork-point`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html#_discussion_on_fork_point_mode).